# How to programmatically map GI numbers directly to HGNC gene names?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, bioservices

I have a collection of ~2000 GI numbers that I need to map to HGNC (aka HUGO) gene names.

I will have to do a similar mapping repeatedly in the future, as part of a data analysis pipeline, so I will like to do this mapping programmatically (as opposed to by cutting-and-pasting the 2K GI numbers on some interactive tool's interface).

Furthermore, I'm constrained to work only with free software.  I am most comfortable with Python and Perl, although I can work ok with R and Java, and as last resort, with anything else (Ruby, MATLAB, Tcl, etc.).

---

(The remainder of this post is not essential to the question.  In it I provide as additional background info, FWIW.  It gets increasingly technical towards the end; this content will be meaningful only to those familiar with NCBI's `eutils` interface.)

One possibility would be to scrape the HGNC id(s) from the web page for each GI number ([example](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/395398606)), but these pages use JavaScript to load their content, which puts them beyond my web scraping abilities.

Even if I could carry out such web scraping, the results are bound to be lower quality than those obtained from a proper web service API.

Unfortunately, I have not found any "official" service to programmatically map GI numbers *directly* to HGNC/HUGO gene names.  The best hope I had for this was NCBI's `eutils` interface, but I was not able to find a way to perform the direct mapping I'm was after.  (Please, correct me if I'm wrong!)

The best I could come up with was a 2-hop mapping: use `eutils` (or rather, the interface to `eutils` provided by the `bioservices.eutils` Python module) to map GI numbers to Entrez Gene IDs, and then use a comprehensive table [downloaded](http://www.genenames.org/cgi-bin/hgnc_downloads) from HGNC to map these Entrez Gene IDs to HGNC/HUGO gene names.

As usual, the "attrition rate" for such a multi-hop mapping is pretty bad: ~25% of all the GI numbers got mapped to *some* HGNC/HUGO gene name.  (I have yet to estimate how many of these mappings are actually correct.)

I attempted doing the first hop of this mapping using Python's `bioservices.eutils` library but was able to get Entrez gene ids for only about one quarter of the 2K GI numbers this way.  More specifically, this is what I used, in essence:

```
from bioservices import EUtils

s = EUtils()
xml = s.ELink(db='gene', dbfrom='protein', Ids='395398606')

# ...now parse the returned xml to get the returned Entrez gene id(s)
```

The call to `s.ELink` results in an HTTP request of the form:

```
http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?db=gene&dbfrom=protein&id=395398606&cmd=neighbor
```

If there's a better `eutils` command to map GI numbers to Entrez gene ids than this, please let me know.  Better yet, if there's a better `eutils` command to map GI numbers directly to HGNC/HUGO gene names, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get what you need from the [UCSC Genome Browser](https://cgwb.nci.nih.gov/goldenPath/gbdDescriptions.html) as a MySql table - this can be queried using most of the languages that you mention but my preference would be python.

Answer (score 0):

If at all I am able to get the information needed from the NCBI through web scraping, what information do you need exactly from those pages. Lets say which details do you need from the [example](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/395398606) you have given.

If at all what you need is available in that page, I can write a code in PHP to get the information you need for any number of GI IDs.